# Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:

```
CREATE TABLE `database1`.`log` (
  `rollnum` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `checkout` TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rollnum`));

ERROR 1067: Invalid default value for 'checkout'
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `database1`.`log` (
  `rollnum` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `checkout` TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rollnum`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fractional precision should be [consistent](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Replace

```sql
`checkout` TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

by

```
`checkout` TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
```